# $p$-adic numbers and residually finiteness

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $J_p$ be the additive group of $p$-adic integers and $Q_p$ be the additive group of $p$-adic numbers. I know that $J_p$ is residually finite.

Is $Q_p$ residually finite?

**Definition**

A group $G$ is said to be *residually finite* if the intersection of all subgroups of finite index is the trivial subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a divisible group and such a group cannot be residually finite.

Edit: for a positive integer $n$ let us consider the statement

$$S_n:\forall x\ \exists y: \underbrace{y+\cdots+y}_{n\text{ times}}=x.$$

An Abelian group $G$ being "divisible" means that $G$ satisfies this sentence for every $n$. Suppose that $G/H$ is a finite quotient of  an Abelian group $G$. Then there exists a positive number $n$ such that for every $gH\in G/H$, $\underbrace{gH+\cdots+gH}_{n}=0$. On the other hand, every quotient of a divisible group must also satisfy all sentences $S_n$. This implies that a divisible group cannot have finite quotients (except the trivial one).

Comment: Could you care to flesh this out some more? For example, it may be helpful to state that divisible groups have no finite index subgroups because...

Comment: @RghtHndSd --- I have edited it (though I believe the OP would have been happy to include the details him/herself).

Comment: You've provided far more details than I had in mind, I should have been more specific. Stating solely that it follows because the group is divisible, when one starts to think about why this is, it may not occur to them that its because of a rather silly reason: that there are no finite nonzero quotients. Knowing that it suffices to prove this stronger statement is actually easier. In any case, the answer here is certainly good.

Comment: @RghtHndSd OK, now I understand. I understood your comment as saying that I should fill the "..." after the "because".

Comment: Thanks! I known the fact that a divisible group cannot be residually finite, I was just missing the fact that $Q_p$ is an additive group of a field and so a direct sum of isomorphic copies of the additive group of the rational numbers.